# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I am trying to create a Jpa repository for a Capteur Class.

I have javax and not jakarta.

Here is my class.

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "capteurs")
public class CapteurJpa {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private UUID id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Embedded
    private CoordonneeJpa coordonnee;
    
    @Min(value = 0, message = "L'intensité du feu ne peut pas être plus basse que 0")
    @Max(value = 10, message = "L'intensité du feu ne peut pas être plus haute que 10")
    private Integer intensite;
    
}
```

And here is my CapteurRepository:

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.repository;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa;

@Repository
public interface CapteurRepository extends JpaRepository<CapteurJpa, UUID> {
    
}
```

In my main I added an entityScan:

```
package fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa")
public class ReferentielReelApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReferentielReelApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

But I still get the managed type error.

I tried using the EntityScan, but the application/main is already in fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel so in subpackages so should find it.

I am completelty lost, I followed many tutorials and topics to correct different possible things that could cause the error but without finding a solution.

Here is my stack

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'capteurRepository' defined in fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.repository.CapteurRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.ReferentielReelApplication.main(ReferentielReelApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel.model.jpa.CapteurJpa
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Thanks for your help

Tried to create an Entity Class that I linked to a JpaRepository.
I tried using the EntityScan, but the application/main is in fr.projettresscientifique.reel.referentielreel so in subpackages so should find it.
I also tried reading similar threads.
I will also develope a controller.
My goal is to then link it to a postgresql database.

Comment: You are using Spring BOot 3 which is JakartaEE not JavaEE. Change the imports. The fact that you have those imports also indicates you are messing around with dependencies yourself instead of relying on Spring Boot starters to pullin the right ones.

Comment: Hi which import should I change ? All the javax ones ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Gochou can you add your pom.xml to your post?

Comment: It is `jakarta.persistence` nowaways and not `javax.persistence`. As I stated the fact that you can even import `javax.persistence` means you included dependencies yourself (persistence-api probably) instead of using the ones provided by `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: It's working with jakarta instead of javax, thanks very much